# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"allans"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one controller "Allan" and one controller "Marian"
They are both equal, and before i created "marian" "allan" was working just fine.
But now, when I try to create a new Alla, I get this:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"allans"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

The problem is that "Marian" works perfectly.

What is wrong?

```
class AllansController < ApplicationController
http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "allan", :password => "allan"
  # GET /allans
  # GET /allans.json
  def index
    @date = Date.parse(params[Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%b %e"]) rescue Date.today
    @allans = Allan.where(day: @date)
    @total_allans   = Allan.count
    @current_allans = @allans.size
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @allans }
    end
  end

  # GET /allans/1
  # GET /allans/1.json
  def show
    @allan = Allan.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @allan }
    end
  end

  # GET /allans/new
  # GET /allans/new.json
  def new
    @allan = Allan.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @allan }
    end
  end

  # GET /allans/1/edit
  def edit
    @allan = Allan.find(params[:id])
      session[:return] ||= request.referer
  end

  # POST /allans
  # POST /allans.json
  def create
    @allan = Allan.new(params[:allan])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @allan.save
        format.html { redirect_to maria_path, notice: 'Maria was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @allan, status: :created, location: @allan }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @allan.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /allans/1
  # PUT /allans/1.json
  def update
    @allan = Allan.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @allan.update_attributes(params[:allan])
        format.html { redirect_to session.delete(:return)}
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @allan.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /allans/1
  # DELETE /allans/1.json
  def destroy
    @allan = Allan.find(params[:id])
    @allan.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to maria_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Marian's cont

```
class MariansController < ApplicationController
http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "maria", :password => "maria"
  # GET /marians
  # GET /marians.json
  def index
    @date = Date.parse(params[Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%b %e"]) rescue Date.today
    @marians = Marian.where(day: @date)
    @total_marians   = Marian.count
    @current_marians = @marians.size
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @marians }
    end
  end

  # GET /marians/1
  # GET /marians/1.json
  def show
    @marian = Marian.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @marian }
    end
  end

  # GET /marians/new
  # GET /marians/new.json
  def new
    @marian = Marian.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @marian }
    end
  end

  # GET /marians/1/edit
  def edit
    @marian = Marian.find(params[:id])
      session[:return] ||= request.referer
  end

  # POST /marians
  # POST /marians.json
  def create
    @marian = Marian.new(params[:marian])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @marian.save
        format.html { redirect_to maria_path, notice: 'Maria was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @marian, status: :created, location: @marian }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @marian.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /marians/1
  # PUT /marians/1.json
  def update
    @marian = Marian.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @marian.update_attributes(params[:marian])
        format.html { redirect_to session.delete(:return)}
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @marian.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /marians/1
  # DELETE /marians/1.json
  def destroy
    @marian = Marian.find(params[:id])
    @marian.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to maria_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

rake routes

```
     allans GET    /allans(.:format)               allans#index
            POST   /allans(.:format)               allans#create
  new_allan GET    /allans/new(.:format)           allans#new
 edit_allan GET    /allans/:id/edit(.:format)      allans#edit
      allan GET    /allans/:id(.:format)           allans#show
            PUT    /allans/:id(.:format)           allans#update
    marians GET    /marians(.:format)              marians#index
            POST   /marians(.:format)              marians#create
 new_marian GET    /marians/new(.:format)          marians#new
edit_marian GET    /marians/:id/edit(.:format)     marians#edit
     marian GET    /marians/:id(.:format)          marians#show
            PUT    /marians/:id(.:format)          marians#update
            DELETE /marians/:id(.:format)          marians#destroy
                   /allan(.:format)                allans#index
      maria        /maria(.:format)                marians#index
       root        /                               intro#index
```

form Allan

```
    <%= form_for(@allan) do |f| %>
      <% if @allan.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@allan.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this allan from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @allan.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Lesson</th>
            <th>Presence</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><%= f.date_select :day %></th>
            <th><%= f.text_field :time, "size" => 4 %></th>
            <th><%= f.text_field :lesson, "size" => 4 %></th>
            <th><%= f.text_field :presence, "size" => 4 %></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />  
      <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>O</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>P</th>
        <th>G</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><%= f.text_field :name %></th>
            <th> <%= f.text_field :oral, "size" => 2 %></th>
            <th> <%= f.text_field :writing, "size" => 2 %></th>
            <th> <%= f.text_field :participation, "size" => 2 %></th>
            <th> <%= f.text_field :grammar, "size" => 2 %></th>
        </tr>
        </table>
      <br />
    <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Observations</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th><%= f.text_field :observation %></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
       <br />
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Create" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

maria

```
    <%= form_for(@marian) do |f| %>
      <% if @marian.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@marian.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this Maria from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @marian.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Lesson</th>
            <th>Presence</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><%= f.date_select :day %></th>
            <th><%= f.text_field :time, "size" => 4 %></th>
            <th><%= f.text_field :lesson, "size" => 4 %></th>
            <th><%= f.text_field :presence, "size" => 4 %></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />  
      <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>O</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>P</th>
        <th>G</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><%= f.text_field :name %></th>
            <th> <%= f.text_field :oral, "size" => 2 %></th>
            <th> <%= f.text_field :writing, "size" => 2 %></th>
            <th> <%= f.text_field :participation, "size" => 2 %></th>
            <th> <%= f.text_field :grammar, "size" => 2 %></th>
        </tr>
        </table>
      <br />
    <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Observations</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th><%= f.text_field :observation %></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
       <br />
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Create" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Based on your code you should be getting an error saying something like undefined method maria_path for allans controller.  But you might have cut and pasted to save some time in stack overflow.  This isn't a very rails-way to go about things, but aside from that I don't see what would produce this error, assuming that you're calling your form from the url `/allans/new` - are you?

Comment: I'm not getting an error about maria. And yes, I'm calling it from the url.

Comment: This is what I get in the console: `Started GET "/allans/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-31 16:44:58 -0200
Processing by AllansController#new as HTML
  Rendered allans/_form.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendered allans/new.html.erb within layouts/application (11.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"allans"}):
  app/views/allans/new.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_allans_new_html_erb__577930706_33554424'
  app/controllers/allans_controller.rb:31:in `new'`

Comment: What is line 5 of new.html.erb ?

Comment: <%= link_to 'Back', allans_path %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what the problem was, but i copied the code from Marias and changed the names "marias" to "allan", and it worked. So maybe was smt I ghanged without noticing.